# BroadcastService restart itself when app killed

Tags: android, android-service, countdowntimer

I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32028134/how-to-keep-a-countdowntimer-running-even-if-the-app-is-closed) broadcast service with countdown timer. But when i kill the app, it is not ticking on same time(second), it is starts again.

Here is my code.

**BroadcastService:**

```
package com.example.emre.denemeprojesi;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class BroadcastService extends Service {

    private final static String TAG = "BroadcastService";

    public static final String COUNTDOWN_BR = "com.example.emre.denemeprojesi";
    Intent bi = new Intent(COUNTDOWN_BR);

    CountDownTimer cdt = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Log.i(TAG, "Starting timer...");
        System.out.println("STARTING TIMER");

        cdt = new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                Log.i(TAG, "Countdown seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                bi.putExtra("countdown", millisUntilFinished);
                sendBroadcast(bi);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Log.i(TAG, "Timer finished");
                System.out.println("TIMER CANCELLED");
            }
        };

        cdt.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();


    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Main Activity:**

```
package com.example.emre.denemeprojesi;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String TAG  ="Countdown Servisi";
    private TextView lblResult ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lblResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lbl_result);

        startService(new Intent(this, BroadcastService.class));
        Log.i(TAG, "Started service");
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            updateGUI(intent); // or whatever method used to update your GUI fields
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter(BroadcastService.COUNTDOWN_BR));
        Log.i(TAG, "Registered broacast receiver");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(br);
       Log.i(TAG, "Unregistered broacast receiver");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        try {
            unregisterReceiver(br);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Receiver was probably already stopped in onPause()
        }
        super.onStop();
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
       // stopService(new Intent(this, BroadcastService.class));
        //Log.i(TAG, "Stopped service");

    }

    private void updateGUI(Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
            long millisUntilFinished = intent.getLongExtra("countdown", 0);
            System.out.println(millisUntilFinished); //<<<bu göstermiyor<<<<<<
            Log.i(TAG, "Countdown seconds remaining: " +  millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            //
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: in onStartCommand return START_STICKY.https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY

Comment: @Raghunandan i did like this ;  but it is not worked  

https://paste.ubuntu.com/23491093/

Comment: what did you do and what happened. and you should post the code instead of the link to the same

Comment: There was no change. i killed the app and timer started again.