# How to create a Timer that updates a TextView from Activity and when the app goes background it keeps running

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm trying to figure it out how to do this, I'd like to create a timer from data that comes by server like : 3600 <-- this comes from server, so I'd like to create a timer with this time and have a TextView that is updating it every 1 second and once the timer is done create a dialog, this is not necessary I know how to do it, but I'd like to do like if user put the app in background timer keeps running.

What I thought is to create a `BroadcastService` and update from there the `TextView` and if the app goes on background in `onPause()` I should do something to keep running the timer, and also thought about if timer is done, add it to a SharedPreferences so I can know if the timer is finished or not (if the user had the app in background).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: If by background you means to recent stack then you can just use a `Handler` or a `Timer` to post each second . Start in `onPause` stop in `onResume` of Application or Activity (whichever the need).

Comment: Background I mean changing to another app

Comment: But then when I'm in onResume how do I know if the task is finished or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Use foreground service we can run countdowntimer that runs in background
```

[Foreground service example Github](https://github.com/InKyu0317/Android-Oreo-Foreground-Service-Simple-Example/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/data/studysensor/androidoreoforegroundtest/MyService.java)

Comment: Please can you help me? I'm using this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/42970754/4385913 and even if I put 5 seconds it puts 5 hours... I want just display the exact time, if I send 5 minutes just a timer with 5 minutes

Comment: i think this is the code you wanna change long int_timer = TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(int_hours); to long int_timer = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(int_hours);

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler) to do the periodic sync in your custom [Application](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application) class. That handler will be destroyed only if your app is killed.

You can extend the Application class to be something like:

```
public class App extends Application {

    private static final long ONE_MINUTE = 60 * 1000;

    private Handler handler;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        this.handler = new Handler();
        this.handler.postDelayed(syncData, ONE_MINUTE);
    }

    private Runnable syncData = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO startSync();
            handler.postDelayed(this, ONE_MINUTE);
        }
    };
}
```

In that Runnable you can do whatever you want e.g. working with shared preferences.

You can set this custom `App` class to be your application class in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="your_package_name">

    <application
        android:name=".App"
        rest of your code .... >
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please can you help me? I'm using this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/42970754/4385913 and even if I put 5 seconds it puts 5 hours... I want just display the exact time, if I send 5 minutes just a timer with 5 minutes

Comment: What numbers do you use when you create the new `CountDownTimer()`?