# How to create offline notifications for android app that do not need the application to be opened

Tags: java, android, notifications

I am developing a calendar application.
I'm starting to get interested in notifications but I have a problem.
Impossible to know how I can send a notification to the user. This notification must appear even if the application is closed and must not require internet.
Does anyone have any idea how to do that?

Comment: You should look at Firebase cloud messaging - https://firebase.google.com/products/cloud-messaging for sending notification to application. But I am not sure if it can work without internet connection.

Comment: Create services that listen to the calendar and clock then call the notification manager depending in your condition. It doesn't require internet. here some example service https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32028134/how-to-keep-a-countdowntimer-running-even-if-the-app-is-closed