# How to build a timer that runs even app is removed from recent tasks?

Tags: android, android-studio, service, countdowntimer

I am trying to build a knowledge based game , in which user plays and win some coins , gems etc.
*My problem is that after the game is over i want to start a `timer` /`service`/`handler` (i dont know basically what to say here) of **5 minutes running in background**... When the timer is over I Award user his prize*.

At present I have used countdown timer and handler with post delayed for that but the problem is that Both `countdowntimer` and `Handler` fails to run if user removes the app from `recent tasks`..the timer is never complete and user never gets his prize. I want to know how can i award the prize after 5 minutes...

A another stackflow user had the similar question [How to keep a CountDownTimer running even if the app is closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32028134/17072466).
The accepted answer he received https://stackoverflow.com/a/42970754/17072466 .
But its 5 year old..i wonder if that will work now due to Oreo+   background process limitations.

Please help me , its above 1 week still i have not resolved it yet.

Comment: Did you try AlarmManager? You can set the time like 5 minutes. When the time is reached, Broadcast receiver class is called.

Comment: @kumar No kumar ..I don't know how to implement that correctly ..can you share a link for that..I just started learning android so dont know much about all stuffs

Comment: Watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xSrVWFCtgaE . I'm not sure but if you run a thread even after closing the app, you get a memory leak. So, I suggest you use AlarmManager.

Comment: @kumar ok thnaks for the link ...just implementing this...will let you knw under 30 min if it works

Comment: @kumar the link you sent will work..but it will give a notification everytime user  finish playing a game. Suppose user plays 10 games in 15 minutes ..so their will be 15 diffrent notofications..  Any way to hide notification?

Comment: In the video, when the alarm is triggered, onReceive() method is called (which is in AlarmReceiver class). Watch the video at 5:22 time. You can write anything you want in the onReceive() method. No need to display the notification.

Comment: i would like to know..is this the correct way of setting an alarm at a given time... suppose i want to set it at 3:50 PM today  ...So we have to do it like this ??

        calender = Calendar.getInstance();
        calender.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,15);
        calender.set(Calendar.MINUTE,50);
        calender.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
        calender.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);

Comment: @kumar yes it is working. Thanks. Would have upvoted the answer if you have answered rather than comment. But anyways thank u so much. But as this is alarm..is their something available as of now that works as timer in background ?

Comment: Great! You can also upvote the comment.