# Android Studio How to use a CountDownTimer in background together with TextView

Tags: android, service, textview, countdowntimer

Well, I am trying to create a CountDownTimer for my app. I already searched on the internet but couldn't find a good solution for my problem.

This Timer should keep running after the user cloese the app or switched to another. So I will need a Service class I think. Then the Timer should be connected to a TextView which refreshes every second. It should count down from 30:00 to 00:00.

Any help appreciated :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run CountDownTimer in a Service in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22496863/how-to-run-countdowntimer-in-a-service-in-android)

Comment: this already has an answer  here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22496863/how-to-run-countdowntimer-in-a-service-in-android

Comment: Thank you very much Rishabh :) I already found that post but thought was confused because I read something about a Service class.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a thread for it in your service

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
       //do stuff here
            }
        });
    }
}).start();
```

or visit [this](http://androidexample.com/Thread_With_Handlers_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=58) or [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any type of service here. `CountDownTimer` class automatically runs on a different thread and gives the callback in UI thread. `CountDownTimer` creates a thread on it's own.

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        binding.nameTxt.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        //here you can have your logic to set text to edittext
        }

    public void onFinish() {
        binding.nameTxt.setText("done!");
        //here you can have your logic to set text to edittext when the timer is stopped.
    }
}.start();
```

Comment: Thank you very much :D I have already seen this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZqqP69rJVmg but as I read something about the Service class for background services I was confused because the findViewById command doesn't work in a Service.                                             Thank you very much again :)

Comment: Hi again. Could you show me the complete Service class? "new CountDownTimer" gives out an error.. Sorry, I am quite new in Service classes. And how is it possible to connect the EditText of my MainActivity with this Service? Thank you very much :)