# What would be the correct way to set up a CountDownTimer to run onDestroy()?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sharedpreferences, countdowntimer

I'm trying to create a timer that would launch in the background once `onDestroy()` is triggered, and once the timer reaches 6 hours, `SharedPreferences` will be used to make a change in the app.

I was wondering... what would be the correct way to setup `CountDownTimer` or anything similar it for `onDestroy()`.

I will answer anything if needed. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using a Service?

Comment: It's not about using a Service and more about what the code to establish the countdown would look like in this scenario.

Comment: it's all about a Service. It's the only way to do what you want.

Comment: I searched for questions similar to mine on how to create a countdown Service, but it doesn't really explain how to launch it only when the app is closed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22496863/how-to-run-countdowntimer-in-a-service-in-android

Comment: Use `startForegroundService()` in your Activity's `onDestroy()` method.

Comment: Looks like the minimum required sdk to use `startForegroundService()` is 26. Only very little amount of phones will be able to use the app in this case. Not a lot of phones are 26. I'll just skip on the countdown thing thanks.

Comment: You can use `ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, serviceIntent)`, which will start it as a foreground service on API 26+ and a normal service on API 25-.

Comment: Yay! I got it working finally. Thank you so much. I will add the answer in about an hour.

Comment: Apparently `startForegroundService` crashes if the app is relaunched after 5 seconds. Seems like no way to get past that. Only for API 26 and above.

Comment: you need to call startForeground inside the Service's onCreate method.

Comment: But I do agree with you. Google forced this behavior on Oreo without properly testing it. You might run into crashes on some devices, since the system won't always start the Service within the 5 second limit.

Comment: Awesome thanks. Now the service works without crashing. Going to make sure that everything works.

Comment: @TheWanderer I've written an answer. SharedPreferences works as intended after an one hour timer, and without the `startForegroundService` crashing. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After about a week, a working answer came up. This answer includes what's related to how to make the service run. In this scenario, I'm building a `CountDownTimer` service.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service android:name=".TimeService"/>
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
       Intent i;

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           i = new Intent(this, TimeService.class);

           stopService(i); //To stop the service the next time the app is launched.
       }

       @Override
       protected void onDestroy() {
           launchService(); //Launches the service once when app shuts down.
           super.onDestroy();
       }

       public void launchService() { //How to launch the service, depending the phone's API.
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
                 startForegroundService(new Intent(this, TimeService.class));
            }
            else{
                Intent i;
                i = new Intent(this, TimeService.class);
                ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, i);
            }
       }
}
```

TimeService.java

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;

public class TimeService extends Service {

   CountDownTimer cdt = null;
   private SharedPreferences pref;
   //Things you want SharedPreferences to change.
   Intent i;

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
       i = new Intent(this, TimeService.class);
       startService(i);
       pref = this.getSharedPreferences("myAppPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
       cdt = new CountDownTimer(3600000, 1000) { //One hour timer with one second interval.

           @Override
           public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

           }

           @Override
           public void onFinish() {
                //Whatever you need SharedPreferences to change here.
           }
       };
       cdt.start();
   }

   @Nullable
   @Override
   public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
       return null;
   }
}
```