# Increase points even app is closed android

Tags: android, android-studio, alarmmanager, system-services

I am new in android and I don't know how to do this, I want to create a **background service**, There is two main component in my app one is **Button (Start Earning)** and another is **TextView (Points)**. I want to create service like if User Open app and *Click on Start Earning Button* then the the points in *TextView* wants to **Increase Continuously For 1 Hour (100 Points In 1 Hour)**. then after *1 hour I want to stop that service automatically even if app is closed*

[Example Is In This Screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vnf7.jpg)

Pls Help Me I Search Every Where (Google,Stackoverflow,Github,etc.) But I Don't Get Any Answer.

Answer (score 0):

The service you are looking to use here is a broadcast service, which broadcast how much time has been passed after button has been pressed. So you can have a broadcast service, which has a `CountDownTimer` for counting down 1hr time. Then you can broadcast the message (containing the points) after a particular time (like after each minute or seconds or after an hour) based on your need. In your fragment/activity you will have an broadcast listener, which will listen to the broadcasted messages (points) and update the UI. You can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/22498307/5309486 answer for the implementation details.